# Map of refs, current is always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm creating a host of a bunch of pages, and those pages are created dynamically. Each page has a function that I'd like to call at a specific time, but when trying to access a ref for the page, the current is always null.

```
export default class QuizViewPager extends React.Component<QuizViewPagerProps, QuizViewPagerState> {

    quizDeck: Deck | undefined;
    quizRefMap: Map<number, React.RefObject<Quiz>>;
    quizzes: JSX.Element[] = [];
    viewPager: React.RefObject<ViewPager>;

    constructor(props: QuizViewPagerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.quizRefMap = new Map<number, React.RefObject<Quiz>>();
        this.viewPager = React.createRef<ViewPager>();
        this.state = {
            currentPage: 0,
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.quizDeck!.litems.length; i++) {
            this.addQuiz(i);
        }
    }

    setQuizPage = (page: number) => {
        this.viewPager.current?.setPage(page);
        this.setState({ currentPage: page })
        this.quizRefMap.get(page)?.current?.focusInput();
    }

    addQuiz(page: number) {
        const entry = this.quizDeck!.litems[page];
        var ref: React.RefObject<Quiz> = React.createRef<Quiz>();
        this.quizRefMap.set(page, ref);
        this.quizzes.push(
            <Quiz
                key={page}
                litem={entry}
                index={page}
                ref={ref}
                pagerFocusIndex={this.state.currentPage}
                pagerLength={this.quizDeck?.litems.length!}
                setQuizPage={this.setQuizPage}
                navigation={this.props.navigation}
                quizType={this.props.route.params.quizType}
                quizManager={this.props.route.params.quizType === EQuizType.Lesson ? GlobalVars.lessonQuizManager : GlobalVars.reviewQuizManager}
            />
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ViewPager
                    style={styles.viewPager}
                    initialPage={0}
                    ref={this.viewPager}
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                >
                    {this.quizzes}
                </ViewPager>
            </View >
        );
    }
};
```

You can see in `addQuiz()` I am creating a ref, pushing it into my map, and passing that ref into the `Quiz` component. However, when attempting to access any of the refs in `setQuizPage()`, the Map is full of refs with null current properties.

Comment: Is Quiz a functional component or a class?

Comment: It's also a class component.

Comment: is `ViewPager` rendering all children, or is it selectively rendering based on the page? This could prevent the `Quiz`es from being mounted.

Comment: Currently, it should be rendering all of them at once. In the constructor I'm creating all of the Quizzes in the for loop, then just throwing that array of JSX Elements in the render

Comment: would need to see the code for ViewPager or know which library it is

Comment: if it is https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager, you can try to focus the input _after_ the viewpager navigates to it with the `onPageSelected` callback instead of doing it in the `setQuizPage` method: `<ViewPager onPageSelected={(pageIndex) => { this.quizRefMap.get(pageIndex)?.current?.focusInput() }} ... >`

Comment: That's a really good call, and I think I will implement it that way. However, the map is still full of objects with null currents. If I do: `onPageSelected={(pageIndex) => console.log(this.quizRefMap)}` then it prints this out:

```Map {
  0 => Object {
    "current": null,
  },
  1 => Object {
    "current": null,
  },
  2 => Object {
    "current": null,
  },
  3 => Object {
    "current": null,
  },
  4 => Object {
    "current": null,
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum it up, the `ViewPager` library being used isn't actually rendering the children you are passing it.

If we look at the source of `ViewPager` (react-native-viewpager), we will see `children={childrenWithOverriddenStyle(this.props.children)}` ([line 182](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/aa9364f0298c1cf9c49704e7a15394c7b7e943fa/js/ViewPager.js#L182)). If we dig into the `childrenWithOverriddenStyle` method, we will see that it is actually ["cloning" the children](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/aa9364f0298c1cf9c49704e7a15394c7b7e943fa/js/utils.js#L39) being passed in via `React.createElement`.

It is relatively easy to test whether or not the `ref` passed to these components will be preserved by creating a little demo:

```js
const logRef = (element) => {
  console.log("logRef", element);
};

const ChildrenCreator = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
      {React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
        console.log("creating new", child);
        let newProps = {
          ...child.props,
          created: "true"
        };
        return React.createElement(child.type, newProps);
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildrenCreator>
        <h1 ref={logRef}>Hello World</h1>
        <p>It's a nice day!</p>
      </ChildrenCreator>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, '#app');
```

([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-bash-7w12f))

If we look at the console when running this, we will be able to see that the output from `logRef` only appears for the first, uncopied h1 tag, and not the 2nd one that was copied.

While this doesn't fix the problem, this at least answers the question of why the refs are null in your Map. It actually may be worth creating an issue for the library in order to swap it to `React.cloneElement`, since `cloneElement` will preserve the `ref`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try forking it and making that change and see if it fixes it, as well.